Where should one define aggregate routes in ISP network?
It's a common practice to advertise aggregate routes to upstream providers or peering partners. However, where should one configure aggregate routes in its own network? Ideally in every router on the network edge which has at least one peering or upstream connection utilizing those aggregate routes?

Great question, Martin!  The answer depends on your network architecture.  If you use IPs at two or more sites, and you aggregate to a single aggregate announcement toward eBGP neighbors, you must maintain connectivity among your sites or they'll become unreachable to parts of the Internet.
For example, if the below network announces only an aggregate 198.18.0.0/22 to all its eBGP neighbors, and the connection === between west-asbr & east-asbr goes down, west-asbr will still be attracting traffic from the Internet bound to 198.18.2.22 but it won't be able to forward that traffic to the East DC.  It'll discard the traffic.
The problem would occurr in both directions and both datacenters would experience degraded service until the === backbone link between them were restored.
     ISP A           ISP B     Peer C
       |                |     /
       |                |    /
   west-asbr ====== east-asbr
       |                |
       |                |
     host1            host2
  198.18.1.11      198.18.2.22

    West DC          East DC

Additionally, if you have a geographically large network, it may be costly to haul traffic around when you could otherwise get your ISPs to do it for you.
Even some of the largest networks, like amazon AWS, prefer to let their transit providers carry a lot of traffic to them in the region where it's ultimately destined, instead of have the carrier "hot-potato" it onto their own networks as soon as possible and use their own backbone.
The relationship to prefix aggregation is important.  It's not great for the Internet to announce lots of small prefixes for routing convenience, because routers don't have unlimited forwarding table space; but when making a decision for your network, you may be strongly motivated to announce those small prefixes, instead of aggregating, due to fault-tolerance (as illustrated above) and cost / capacity reasons.
IPv6 makes this a bit easier than IPv4 since we are less likely to grow to a big number of prefixes per site.
I hope this helps!  I'd be happy to further clarify if you can add any specific details to your question.

Thanks! Based on your example, should one advertise an aggregate 198.18.0.0/22 plus more-specific 198.18.1.0/24 at West DC and an aggregate 198.18.0.0/22 plus 198.18.2.0/24 at East DC? This should provide the connectivity for both DCs even in case the === link fails or one DC loses all its peers/ISPs?

You can do so but in that case, you're announcing three routes to the DFZ instead of one or two -- kind of a worst-case scenario.  However, if you have exactly the same transit providers at both sites (and generally, no settlement-free peers) you can announce the /22, also announce the /24s but with a no-export community or similar, and get fault tolerance without polluting the DFZ (only pollute the transit provider's network with the /24s; and you do pay them so it's okay)!

Yes, unless you have more than one connection to the upstream provider.  In that case, you probably don't want to aggregate so you don't blackhole routes.
